# Variable listener between 2 classes

Tags: java, class, variables, listener

I have a problem for a month ago :S .This is it:

I have 3 classes:

Class 1:

TabbedPane with a MouseListener, when someone click on a tab, the mouse listener change a variable called "update".

This class have a method like this:

```
public boolean getUpdateMenuState(){
    //Creates the update variable 
    boolean update = false;
    //If a update is necessary
    if(needUpdate = true){    //Need update is defined at top of the class
        //Reset the update variable
        needUpdate = false;
        //Set the getUpdate variable to true
        update = true;
        System.out.println("The menu needs to be updated");
    }
    //return the update
    return update;

}
```

The second class, is the main:

This class needs to know if the variable needUpdate changes, I have this method:

```
private void updateMenu(){
    //Create a variable update
    boolean update = false;
    //Set the variable update to the get state
    update = myTabbedPane.getUpdateMenuState();
    //If a update is requiered, re-add the menu
    if(update){
        menu.addMenu(); //Call the third class that have the method addMenu
    }
}
```

My problem is that I need to know constantly if the variable needUpdate is changed, and I don't know how to implement my own listener to do it.
I can't call the third class directly in the first class because I want to centralize the control on the second class.

Please, if someone can help me I'll be grateful.

Comment: is update meant to hold the same value as needUpdate?  Have you considering using setters and getter?  Better yet, this looks like a good example for the Observer pattern to know when a value changes.

Comment: You need to read and implement the Observer pattern. Also check java observable.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't extend it because I already extend a JFrame :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic example where an Observer pattern is the ideal solution. Refer to this [Implementing Observer Pattern](http://techtipsjava.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/implementing-observer-pattern.html) post for the details of how to implement the Pattern.

PS: just saw your reply to one of the answers; 
Best in your situation is to use a Class instead of the boolean variable and you can extend that class.

Comment: I just tried to do it, but I have a problem when I need to do this:  menuOb.addObserver(new Main());  I'm generating the app another time :S because the main is my observer.

Comment: Solved, I just added the main on the constructor of the other class and it works with menuOb.addObserver(main()); :)

Answer (score 0):

I would think that this is a classic case for using the Observer Design Pattern. Class 2 would be the Observer for things happening on the Subject i.e. Class 1 and do what it needs to do when it gets notified i.e. call addMenu() on Class 3.